# Pass single textbox value to the ajax call using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using pricing tables. It is having multiple plans with Amount Textbox. Every plan have submit Button. So user can change the textbox value. By clicking submit function the particular pricing table value should pass to the ajax function.

**Html Code:**

```
<div class="pricing_table">
            <h3 class="title">RD195</h3>
                <span class="price">Rs.195</span>
                   <ul class="features">
                        <li>10 items</li>
                        <li>Unlimited</li>
                         <li><input type="text" class="discountAmount" value="176" style="width:75px;" /></li>
                        <li>7 Days</li>
                  </ul>
                   <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" onclick="javascript:Plans.Subscribe('RD195','RDPurchase','195');return false;">Subscribe</a>
                  <%--<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return vas_confirmcandi('RD195','RDPurchase','195')">Subscribe</a>--%>
             </div>
          </div>

         <div class="pricing_table">

            <h3 class="title">RD545</h3>
                <span class="price">Rs.545</span>
                   <ul class="features">
                        <li>50 items </li>
                        <li>Unlimited</li>
                          <li><input type="text" class="discountAmount" value="491" style="width:75px;" /></li>
                        <li>30 Days</li>
                  </ul>
                   <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" onclick="javascript:Plans.Subscribe('RD545','RDPurchase','545');return false;">Subscribe</a>
                  <%--<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return vas_confirmcand('RD545','RDPurchase','545')">Subscribe</a>--%>
             </div>
```

i want to take the value of **discount amount** to pass the ajax function. But when i click second table amount of **545**, the submit function it is always taking the first value of **176**

**My Ajax Code:**

```
Plans.Subscribe = function (planName, Description, amount){
    var data = $('input[class=discountAmount]').val();
    $("#wait").show();
    if (planName != undefined) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/plans/getdetail",
            data: { 'Plan': plan, 'Type': Description, 'Amount': amount, 'DiscountAmount': data },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.Success) {
                    $("#wait").hide();
                } else {
                   $("#wait").hide();
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                $("#wait").hide();
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Plans.Subscribe pass one more param for discountAmount ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('input[class=discountAmount]').val()` or more typically written as `$('input.discountAmount').val()` is always going to return the value of the first input that matches that selector.  You need to specify WHICH input you want, rather than ALL inputs with the class `.discountAmount`.

The easiest way to do this would be to assign an ID to each of those inputs with some value you're already passing to your function.  For example `planName`.  Then you could simply do `$('#' + planName).val()`

Your input would look like this:

```
<input type="text" id="RD195" class="discountAmount" value="176" style="width:75px;" />
```

Comment: is there any way to pass without call id. because i am having so many table plans.

Comment: @PoliDev you could use :nth-type-of selectors https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/